# Make an app behave as if it is on kitkat

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifast.fsm&hl=en) that worked well on my i9100 (Samsung Galaxy S2) with a custom Kitkat rom. Now, I have installed CM12 (Lollipop) and this app isn't working as it should have.

It shows a login screen, clicking "sign in" on which it throws an error (invalid login. server not responding. Please try again later). This didn't show up when the phone was on Kitkat.

Is there a way whereby I can tell the app that it is running on kitkat or run an app in compatible mode(?)

Comment: More information is needed.  Which app? What is the error it's showing?

Comment: @Chahk: Updated the question with link to the app and the error message. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: You should probably just contact the app developer. If Lollipop broke something they'll need to release a fix for it.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Sure. Lets say that is going to take time. I wanted to see if there is a way whereby I can tell the app to run in compatible mode, assuming Lollipop supports backwards compatibility.

Comment: Apps SHOULD be forward compatible-- new capability is added to Android updates, but a lot of care is taken by Google to try to make sure that older apps won't break on newer Android.  That said, you're sure it's not a new or temporary issue with the server? Can you verify it still runs from a kitkat device?  I'd check [logcat](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Logcat) for clues (errors can actually be kind of descriptive) and contact FSM Mobile with whatever you discover so they can fix the issue.